# Local atmospherejs repository

Tags: meteor, repository, local

I want to setup full clone of atmospherejs on local server for using with meteor. 
Is there any way to do it ?
I understand that every meteor package is hosted on github. Where or how can I find a list of all packages and their git urls ?

Comment: why do you want to that?

Comment: We have isolated developers network (for security reasons) and i'am trying to setup all popular repositories (atmosphere, npm, debian etc..) in this network.

Comment: Good luck with that... you need to clone the atmospherejs db which presumably isn't exposed anywhere.

Comment: I found a way. `curl --header "Accept: application/json" https://atmospherejs.com/a/packages` will get you list of all packages with their git urls registered on atmospherejs.com in json format.

Comment: But still don't have a clue how to setup local repository for our developers team... 8(